# Is there a word that starts with "ы"?

Tags: лексикон, орфография, правописание, буквы

I remember from my school years that there is no such thing as a word that starts with 'ы'. Is this true? If so, is there something fundamental that prevents this from happening? If no, can anybody give an example?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Rather than trying to compile a list of proper nouns and loan-words with initial **Ы**, I'll try to present a more linguistical view on the question.

The vowels /ы/ and /и/ are in the complementary distribution in the Russian language. Moscow Phonological School even asserted that /ы/ and /и/ are actually one phoneme:

> Поскольку в русском языке, по мнению сторонников МФШ, отсутствуют фонетические положения, в которых встречались бы и звук [и], и [ы], то есть присутствие в некоторой позиции одного из этих звуков исключает возможность присутствия в ней другого, последователями школы делается вывод о том, что [и] и [ы] являются разновидностями одной фонемы: [ы] представляет собой вариацию фонемы <и>, обусловленную положением после твёрдого согласного. Таким образом, в парах, подобных *мыл* — *мил*, единственное фонемное различие состоит в мягкости или твёрдости согласного, а не в гласных фонемах. — [Московская фонологическая школа](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0#.D0.93.D0.BB.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5)

Now, if there are no minimal pairs on /ы/—/и/, the phonetic difference between these vowels is merely the assimilation of the preceding consonant: /ы/ follow hard consonants, /и/ follows soft (palatalized) ones.

Hence, with no preceding consonant, only one of the variants can appear. Naturally, it's /и/, and /ы/ should thus be considered an allophone.

For an alternate view (of Leningrad Phonological School), see [shabunc's answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/717/119).

Nevertheless, in loanwords coming from languages where /ы/ *is* a phoneme (take Kazakh, for example), the initial /ы/ is kept for the sake of transcription (same thing as **Ю** in *парашют* ‘parachute’ to better render the French /y/ vowel, even though *-шю-* is impossible in Russian words).

Comment: this is very interesting

Comment: Звуки Ы и И очевидно разные. Если эти звуки растянуть: мыыыыл — мииииил, Вы услышите разницу, не связанную с твёрдостью/мягкостью. Растяните твёрдый и мягкий звуки, они будут в конце одинаковы: маааааты — мяааааата.

Comment: @A-K: The allophones are different phonetic realizations (i.e., sounds) of a single phoneme. So the sounds are different, but as there are no minimal pairs based on them, they can still be folded into a single phoneme. Compare /k/ in _kit_ (aspirated) and _skill_ (unaspirated). The sounds are indeed different, but as there are no minimal pairs on aspirated/unaspirated /k/ in English, there is still one phoneme /k/.

Comment: @helgi, there is also another point of view on this issue, checkout my answer. Тут питерцы тоже с москвичами расходятся во взглядах )))

Comment: @A-K Actually "мя-ааааа" makes a different "a" sound unlike "а" in "маааа".

Answer (score 18):

You will not find common Russian words beginning with 'ы'. However you can encounter proper names, geographical location names that in Russian will start with 'ы' (or 'и' optionally).

These words come from other languages (foreign languages, languages of native population etc).

> Ыгыатта, -ы (р., Якутия, РФ)
>
> Ыджыдпарма, -ы (Ыджидпарма) (возв., Респ. Коми, РФ)
>
> Ылыч, см. Илыч
>
> ЫЛЬЧИ МУНДОК, Ыльчи Мундока (кор. полководец)
>
> Ыныкчанский, -ого (пгт, Якутия, РФ)
>
> Ыспарта, -ы (Испарта) (гор., Турция)
>
> ЫссыкАта, см. ИссыкАта

Also, there is a verb stemming from the letter name: ыкать (cf. окать, акать).

Comment: Nice call on "ыкать"

Comment: Очень много заимствованых\транслителированных слов и имен из корейского на Ы, к примеру "Ким Чен Ын"

Answer (score 12):

There is a rare word *ы́кать*, which actually means ‘to pronounce words with Ы instead of И’.

Here is a [quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_phonology) on a subject:

> A long-standing dispute among linguists is whether Russian possesses
>   five vowel phonemes or six; that is, scholars disagree as to whether
>   [ɨ] constitutes an allophone of /i/ or if there is an independent
>   phoneme /ɨ/. The five-vowel analysis, taken up by the Moscow school,
>   rests on the complementary distribution of [ɨ] and [i], with the
>   former occurring after hard (non-palatalized) consonants and [i]
>   elsewhere.
>
> The six-vowel view, held by the Saint-Petersburg (Leningrad) phonology
>   school, points to several phenomena to make its case:
>
> - Native Russian speakers' ability to articulate [ɨ] in isolation (for example, in the names of respective letters, "и" and "ы")
> - Rare instances of word-initial [ɨ] (including the minimal pair *и́кать* ‘to produce the sound и’ and *ы́кать* ‘to produce the sound ы’),
>     as well as names and toponyms, like *Ыб* [ɨp], the name of a river and
>     several villages in the Komi Republic.

Comment: LOL. You can take ANY sound even that does not exist in Russian and add -кать so to produce a "verb".

Comment: @Anixx, мы уже с вами обсуждали, я потом пошёл и прочёл книгу по близкой теме. Вы правы, но правы в рамках Московской школы.

Comment: Я не прав, что можно взять любой звук(даже непроизносимый) и сделать из него глагол?

Comment: ну вы как бы отрицаете существование слова, которое есть. можно сказать Т-кать но так не говорят. А акать и окать говорят. А ыкать - это тоже вполне живое редкое слово. А говорить перед каждой третьей фразой LOL невежливо.

Comment: "можно сказать Т-кать но так не говорят." почему? "тэкать". Можно взять любой звук, даже которого в русском нет. Хоть thекать, хоть hекать.

Comment: @Anixx В отличие от "тэкать" слово ыкать есть в [Орфографическом словаре РАН](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%FB%EA%E0%F2%FC)

Comment: @Artemix значит, его туда включили специально для этой теориии. Вообще, это регулярное образование - <какой-то звук>+"кать"

Comment: @Anixx Тем не менее в словаре для "экать" места не нашлось. А вот здесь написано про людей которые [ыкают](http://vladim.ir/2011/07/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0/): "Некоторые люди, особенно говорящие зычно и низко, басом,  ыкают.  «Ызба». «Ыкономия» (но только в произношении, не в написании)".

Comment: "Но звук [ы] в абсолютно сильной позиции, т.е. под ударением в начале слова, бывает только в названии буквы ы и в производных от него *узкоспециальных терминах ыкать, ыканье*. На вопрос же о том, есть ли в РЯ фонема <ы>, противопоставленная другим гласным фонемам, как в терминах ыкать, ыканье, следует ответить: есть, но только в подсистеме необщеупотребительных (редких) слов." [(отсюда)](http://www.durov.com/study/yazykoz-542.doc)

Comment: @Artemix единственная причина, почему это слово есть в словаре - потому что такая буква есть в алфавите. В устной речи могут быть аналогичные глаголы со звуками, отсутствующими в русском языке (можно сказать"ðекать", но в ловарь это слово не внесешь - буквы такой в русском языке нету).

Comment: @Anixx Тем не менее в словаре нет "экать", хотя буква "э" в словаре есть.

Comment: @Artemix в Ефремовой есть, как и "эканье".

Comment: @Artemix, ну не хочет человек признавать, что любой носитель русского легко отличает на слух И от Ы - так и пусть. Собственно, даже лингвисты спорят о том же)))

Comment: @shabunc я этого не утверждал.

Comment: @Anixx Я так понял что проблема якобы в том что нет слов отличающихся только буквами ы и и? Их есть у меня: Язик - маленький язь (рыба), Язык - который во рту. Дым - который из трубы, Дим - краткое обращение к Диме. Сир - обращение к королю, сыр - котоый едят. Вилы - орудие труда и выли - "волки выли". "Он - лыс", то есть лысый; и "он - лис", то есть хитрый.

Comment: @Artemix они отличаются мягкостью/твердостью согласных.

Comment: Orthographically, there is a limited number of words that begin with ы, however phonetically, I think it is a more common occurrence. I have a friend whose husband is named Иван and when she says things like от Ивана, с Иваном, she says [aтыва́на] and [сыва́ном], respectively. Is this common or is she ыкатing? Incidentally, when she talks about her husband AND her son, she say [ива́ныса́ша] :)

Answer (score 7):

### On modern usage of Ы-words.

The absense of words starting from letter **Ы** was challenged by many creative people in literature and cinema. The letter itself become a codename for "cover operation" in ["Операция "Ы" movie](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%C2%AB%D0%AB%C2%BB_%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A8%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC)) and a name of a fictional animal [Вепрь Ы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%AB) from the SF-book by Strugatskies ["Трудно быть богом"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC).

To my mind, the most influential nowadays is the cult film "Кин-дза-дза" by Georgiy Daneliya. It depicts a high-tech alien civilization with primitive culture. The aliens used Ы as interjection to show any kind of emotions ranging from anger to happiness. 
This usage of letter Ы become very popular in the Internet, so you can see that people use **ы** or even **ыыы** to show different emotions:

> После выхода фильма «Кин-дза-дза» буква «Ы» также стала использоваться в качестве обозначения смеха или любых сильных, но невербализуемых эмоций. ([Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AB#.C2.AB.D0.AB.C2.BB_.D0.B2_.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BA.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B5.2C_.D0.BA.D1.83.D0.BB.D1.8C.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B5.2C_.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.85.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B5_.D0.B8_.D0.98.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BD.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.B5))

Another reason why Ы become popular to describe laugh is its visual similarity to English lol (laughing out loud) acronym.

Now, when usage of "ыыы" become more common the word "ыкать" from "rare linguistic term to denote usage of ы instead of и" began to mean just "extensive usage of ы":

> Loki: ы, клева
>   pyatachyok: чем ыкать да угукать, не забудь про десктоп, апач и инет :) ([board.rt.mipt.ru](http://board.rt.mipt.ru/?read=4746238))

Looks like this was only the beginning of intensive usage of Ы. [Словарь молодежного сленга](http://teenslang.ru/) lists the following [words starting from Ы](http://teenslang.ru/?page=1&novar=1&content=%D0%AB*):

> **Ы**,  1. междометие. Обозначение громкого смеха, иногда с повторением ыыы.
>   2. предикатив. Выражение насмешки, издевки. Пример: Ы!!! Ржу!!! Ни как лошадь, конечно!
>   Синонимы: ыыы , гы, хы.
>
> **Ыбло**, -а, ср. идея сценария флэшмоба, которая уже была проведена. (анаграмма от было).
>
> **Ыть**, междометие
>   1 так, да, используется дли усиления подтверждения, выражения эмоциональной окраски. 2: оп, опа. Пример текста: Ыть в конце концов - есть-таки положительные результаты. • Ыть, я псых. • Ыть держите меня семеро, модерите меня в три руки. • Ыть я никуда не собирался ваабще-та.
>
> **Ычк**, местоим., сущ., нареч. Все, всё. Происходит из систематической ошибки: на клавиатуре компьютера клавиши «ы» «ч» «к» расположены рядом с клавишами «в» «с» «е».
>   Пример текста: И мой низкий поклон и Мэру и Администрации, я думаю у них ычк получится. • Правильный ответ в окошечке с кодом (1,1,1,1) в котором имеются ычк четыре признака. • Да мне по барабону ычк, что ты сказал. • Вроде бы, я ычк поимаю. • да Да я ычк знаю, но фотки клёвые. • • Как-то размыто ычк. • Ычк мужики по натуре охотники — добиваются того, чего хотят.
>
> **Ышник**, -а, м. Уважаемый человек в обществе. Пример текста: Он назвал его ышником, после чего они вместе бежали по коридору и кричали ы... Синонимы: наш человек.
>
> **Ыыы**, междометие. Возглас выражения эмоций, чаще всего смеха, усмешки, но иногда плача, разочарования и др. Пример текста: Ыыыыыыы, это так кульно! • Ыыы вот так я отдыхал по весне. • Ыыы! лошадка то мля злая попалась! • Я тоже употребляю «ыыы», «гыыыы», «бугагаа». • Ыыы - опять же смех, а точнее передача текстом гортанного звука при глухом смехе. • Ыыы убится мона всё ыыы да ыыы!! • ЫЫы, непруха! • Ни плакай... ЫыЫ... Всё образуется!! Синонимы: гыы, бугага.

[Словарь синонимов on dic.academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru/contents.nsf/dic_synonims/?f=0YjQu9Cw0LM=&t=0Y3Qu9C10Lo=&nt=3910&p=70) along with words mentioned above adds the following: **ычно** (классно, круто, непонятно, ржачно, смешно, странно), **ыка** (заика), **ыжлость** (грусть, уныние), **ыжливший** (грустивший, унывавший), **ыгы** (ага), etc. Looks like ычно, ыжлость, ыжливший also exploit the meaning of "ы" as "strong unverbalizable emotion" which can be "cool or funny or strange or incomprehensible or anything else".

Talking about more traditional words starting from Ы, its worth to mention that Ы itself is a word - the name of letter Ы:

> **Ы**, неизм. 
>   1. ж. и ср.
>   Двадцать девятая буква русского алфавита, обозначающая гласный звук [ы]. Строчное ы.
>   2. м.
>   Гласный звук [ы],
>   обозначаемый этой буквой. Ударное ы. ([Большой толковый словарь](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%FB&all=x))
>
> **Ы** (произн. также еры (устар.)), нескл., ср. название буквы "ы", название соответствующего звука и другие значения: ср. а 1; см. также еры. ([Толковый словарь Ушакова](http://ushakovdictionary.ru/word.php?wordid=87030))

Though it may seem trivial that letter "Ы" has name "Ы", though for many other letters it is not so. For instance "Э" is "э оборотное", "Й" - "и краткое", "Б" is read as "бэ", "К" as "ка", "С" as "эс" and so on and so forth.

P. S. After searching for different examples of modern usage of words starting from letter Ы I found a [good article on Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AB) that summarizes many answers already given. (By the way, in modern internet slang P.S. is written **З. Ы.** since these correspond to the same letters on the Russian keyboard).

Answer (score 4):

When I was a kid I used to like playing "Cities", when you name a city and the next person has to name another city that starts with the last letter of the previous city.  Of course, there is a problem when you have to respond to `Афины` or `Апатиты`.  However, I have an atlas that lists a town named [Ытык Кюёль](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AB%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%9A%D1%8E%D1%91%D0%BB%D1%8C).  Not really a regular word, but it does start with `Ы`

Comment: And the next city starts with ь, that must also be not so easy )

Comment: Well, the last sound was soft L , so most of the cities beginning with La will be OK =)

Answer (score 3):

ыых - a two-string instrument used, e.g., in Khakassia

Comment: That sounds like the Qazaq instrument that i know as a dombra.

Answer (score 2):

Two more... from Русский орфографический словарь:

- `ыр` -а (песня у нек-рых тюркских народов)
- `ых` межд.

Answer (score 0):

The alternate form of /ы/ is /и/. For some reason, the latter was chosen as the vowel with which words start.

Answer (score 0):

Ыллымах — посёлок (до 2005 года посёлок городского типа) в Алданском улусе республики Якутии. Почтовый индекс — 678920.